# CheckDelegate QML Displays only first element

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

So I've got this code:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
ListView {
    model: ["Option X", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
    delegate: CheckDelegate {
        text: modelData
    }
}
```

But it's showing me only the first element:

[image]

QML reference: [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-checkdelegate.html#checkState-prop) , what am I missing?

Comment: you could provide a [mcve], with the code you provide, I get the following: https://imgur.com/a/04h6Z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ListView` do not displays all its element at once. It displays the element  as they "come into view" in its contentItem.

The ListView implicitHeight and implicitWidt are 0, so by default, only the first element is created and displayed, and flick is disabled, since there's no area to click on.

You have to manually set your ListView's height and width.
Width and height can take any value you like (for height, preferably a multiple of the delegate's height, or contentItem's height if you want to display all the items at once)